# Laravel 5.8 - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried to display data inside a table for admin.

Here is my admin.blade.php:

```
<form method="post" action="post_namaadmin">
    <input type="text" name="txtnamaadmin" id="txtnamadmin" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="btnnamadmin" id="btnamaadmin">
</form>
<div class="card-body">
      <table border="1">
          @foreach($datalama as $rows)
          <tr>
              <td>ID : </td>
              <td>{{ $rows->userid }}</td>
              <td>Nama : </td>
              <td>{{ $rows->nama }}</td>
          </tr>
          
        <tr>
            <td>Section</td>
            <td>IM</td>
            <td>CO</td>
            <td>SH</td>
            <td>PL</td>
            <td>RI</td>
            <td>ME</td>
            <td>TB</td>
            <td>CF</td>    
        </tr>
          
          <tr>
              <!-- //1 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h1 }}</td>
              <!-- //1 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a2 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b2 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c2 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d2 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f2 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g2 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h2 }}</td>
              <!-- //3 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h3 }}</td>
              <!-- //4 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a4 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b4 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c4 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d4 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f4 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g4 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h4 }}</td>
              <!-- //5 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a5 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b5 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c5 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d5 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f5 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g5 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h5 }}</td>
              <!-- //6 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a6 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b6 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c6 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d6 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f6 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g6 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h6 }}</td>
              <!-- //7 --> 
              <td>{{ $rows->a7 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->b7 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->c7 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->d7 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->f7 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->g7 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $rows->h7 }}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
      </table>
</div>
```

The code is not yet completed, but it should give a rough picture of the table.

Here is my route in web.php:

```
Route::post('/post_namaadmin', 'DataController@admin' ) ->name ('postnamaadmin');
```

Function in DataController.php :

```
public function admin(Request $request){
        $mk                 = new data();
        $param['datalama']  = $mk->ambilData($request->txtnamaadmin);
        return view('admin',$param);
    }
```

Function in data class :

```
public function ambilData($nama){
        $query = data::orderby('userid')->where('nama','=' ,'$nama')->first();
        return $query;
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
> ErrorException {#230 ▼   #message: "Invalid argument supplied for
> foreach()"   #code: 0   #file:
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\kuesioner1\storage\framework\views\5c1b0932d9bc5a402e110419f0ce7e166c7a2109.php"
> #line: 22   #severity: E_WARNING } 1
```

I'm new in Laravel. For why I use 5.8, my superior demand me so. All help and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: used query like this, $query = data::orderby('userid')->where('nama',$nama)->first();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to `dd($param['datalama'])`, you will get `null`, because your query found nothing, using `->where('nama','=' ,'$nama')`.

You need to change data class `ambilData` method

```
public function ambilData($nama){
    return data::orderby('userid')
        ->where('nama', $nama)
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `$param['datalama']`  in the foreach instead

and change the view function to `view('admin',compact('param'))`

and in the form tag you need to change the action to

```
<form action="{{route('postnamaadmin')}}">
```

Comment: it gave me error `Undefined variable: param`.

Comment: and when you call view, it should be: `view('admin',['param' => $param])` in this case. Otherwise, for your original foreach to work you could send `view('admin',['datalama' => $param['datalama']])`

Comment: as @user3532758 said, and you can also use `view('admin',compact('param'))`

Comment: @omaresmaeel I think you should edit the answer to include these. Just a suggestion.

Comment: May i ask what is compact() user for ?

Comment: its just passing your variable to the view, 
the same as `view('admin',['param' => $param])` but a bit shorter

Comment: i tried all suggestion above, but it gave me either `Undefined variable: param` or the original `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: could you `dd($param)`

Comment: i think  its because my function return wrong data? Did i code the query wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236632/discussion-between-omar-esmaeel-and-romario-rio).